# Haskell Riak driver: Making a simple 'put' operation

Tags: haskell, riak

I am trying to introduce myself to Riak with Haskell driver and I am stuck with a simple `put` operation. I am confused with the signature of the `put` function. and there isn't a single example anywhere out there.

So with this signature:

```
put :: (FromJSON c, ToJSON c, Resolvable c) => Connection -> Bucket 
       -> Key -> Maybe VClock -> c -> W -> DW -> IO (c, VClock)
```

I have a couple of questions.

What is a Maybe VClock? Do I have to generate it somehow or is it enough to just specify Nothing there? And why do I get this VClock back in the returned tuple?

Do I have to write FromJSON and ToJSON instances for every simple value I put even if it is a simple string value? Like if I want to put a value "Stitch" with the key "Name", how do I do it?

What is `Resolvable` instance? How do I make a Text or String value resolvable?
I understand that I have to define the `resolve` function but I don't quite get what it means and how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope following code of simple put and get operation may help you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Main where
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Network.Riak as Riak 
import Network.Riak.Types
import Data.ByteString.Char8 hiding (putStrLn)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as L hiding (pack,putStrLn)
import GHC.Generics hiding (R)

-- convert String to lazy ByteString
toBS :: String -> L.ByteString
toBS str = L.fromChunks (pack (str):[])

putBucket :: Bucket
putBucket = toBS "Bucket"

putKey :: Key
putKey = toBS "key"

r :: R
r = Default

w :: W
w = Default

dw :: DW
dw = Default

rw :: RW
rw = Default 

-- declare a data and create its instances
data Coord = Coord { x :: Double, y :: Double } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Coord

instance ToJSON Coord

instance (Show Coord) => Riak.Resolvable Coord where
    resolve a b = a

value :: Coord
value = Coord {
  x = 2.2,
  y = 3.3
}


main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- establish a connection
    let client = Riak.defaultClient
    con <- Riak.connect client
    -- simple put operation
    put_ret <- (Riak.put con putBucket putKey Nothing value w dw)
    putStrLn (show put_ret)
    buckets <- Riak.listBuckets con
    print buckets
    -- simple get operation
    get_ret <- (Riak.get con putBucket putKey r) :: IO ( Maybe (Coord, VClock))
    putStrLn (show get_ret)
    -- delete a value
    Riak.delete con putBucket putKey rw
    -- if try to get that value we will find "Nothing"
    get_ret <- (Riak.get con putBucket putKey r) :: IO ( Maybe (Coord, VClock))
    putStrLn (show get_ret)
    -- print the final bucket list
    buckets <- Riak.listBuckets con
    print buckets
```

Answer (score 4):

`Maybe VClock` is either the VClock of the object you are updating (`Just vclock`) or `Nothing`. You can specify `Nothing` here if there is no object for this key already in the database.

The `VClock` wrapped in IO (`IO (c, VClock)`) is the VClock of the inserted object, returned from the database.

Your datatype will need a `ToJSON` and a `FromJSON` instance to use that `put` function. [Aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.3/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:11) has instructions for writing this automatically. You can store non-JSON data by using the `Network.Riak.Value` modules, but this is more complicated.

Resolvable is used for resolving two siblings and looks like this where `a` and `b` are `MyDataType`s:

`instance Resolvable MyDataType where
  resolve a b = a`

Ideally your resolve function does something more intelligent than just picking `a` or `b` as the ordering is not guaranteed and may be called multiple times if there are multiple siblings.

[here](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/snaplet-riak-2/blob/master/src/Snap/Snaplet/Riak.hs) is some code for creating a pool of Riak connections you may find useful.

You will end up with something that looks like this:

`put conn bucket key Nothing value Quorum Quorum`

where `value` is your data. More on `Quorum` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/riak-0.7.0.3/docs/Network-Riak-Types.html#t%3aQuorum).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I kind of got the VClock. I got that value has to be a JSON. I understand Quorum too. But I did not get the `Resolvable` side of it. So every time I insert a value I have to make it an instance of `Resolvable` and implement `resolve` function, is this correct? So how do I write this `resolve` function? Can you show a simple example, please?